# How do I convert blender render materials to cycles materials in 2.78c?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, conversion

I have found the articles describing the python scripts to automatically convert, but the scripts seem to have been deleted, presumably because they have stopped working.  For example, looking for materials_cycles_converter.py in the diffusion browser produces the message "This path does not exist at rBAC89bfa619831c. It was deleted in 7d7b8c7d3efc and last existed at rBAC3f433bbe91fd."
Is there an alternative script that I haven't found?  Or a tutorial?

-- edit: I originally mistakenly used 'textures' where I should have used 'materials' in the title.

Comment: That answer and the thread it points to refer to the scripts I mentioned that don't seem to exist any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internal material to cycles material script: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B82io9kDE0ILTi1lazFFV3p4SXM

Install the add-on to Blender:
[image: Add-on]

[image: Conversion]

Sadly it doesn't seem to work with any other textures then your diffuse one (however I may be wrong due to lack of experience with setting up nodes in internal). Although, I would say this is a pretty good start, as it does indeed convert from internal to cycles.

Hope this helps...

Comment: that's an older version of the script that was deleted from diffusion.  It only handles fairly simple materials, but, as you say, it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

Cycles doesn't really have textures like Blender Render. The textures in cycles only affect the colour of the shader. If you want to have an image texture in cycles, first you got to go to the materials tab and turn your material into a cycles material. Second you open the compositor of the material you just converted. Normally there should be a diffuse shader node and material output node. You also got to add two other nodes: Texture coordinate and image texture. Connect the image texture node with the colour input of the shader node and the texture coordinate node with the image texture node. Select your image in the image texture node and then it should work, if I haven't forgot something.

Comment: Apologies for using 'textures' where 'materials' was the correct word.